# JavaScript Accessing Functions within functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
A(); // prints 'a'

function A() { console.log('a'); }
function B() {
    function C() { console.log('c'); }
    function D() { console.log('d'); }
    console.log('b');
}
```

How do I call function C or D from outside of B without changing the contents of function B durastically?

For example, I **don't** want to change B() to be like this:

```
function B(arg)
{
 function C() { console.log('c'); }
 function D() { console.log('d'); }

 if (arg == 'C')
  C();
 if (arg == 'D')
  D();

 console.log('b');
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to modify B()?

Comment: Because I need to be able to call B() without arguments, I don't want to have to specify arguments to B() each time. C() and D() need to be inside B() for convenience.

Comment: If you define functions to be within a particular scope, you can't access them outside that scope. If you could, it would entirely defeat the purpose of variable scope.

Comment: You don't have to specify arguments to B even after the modification. It's just that if you don't pass anything in, C and D will not be called.

Comment: Function declarations and variables (via `var`) have the *same* scope - the identifier is bound to the enlcosing function block. Generally an aggregate group of functions is exposed via properties of a returned objects.

Comment: If you think about it, it's impossible to call `C` and `D` outside `B`. `C` and `D` only exist while `B` is running. You are not even calling `B` so it can't be running. Furthermore, while `B` is running, not other can execute since JS is single threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C()` and `D()` are local functions that are private to the scope of `B()`.  They are like local variables.  They only exist within the scope of `B()`.  That is how the scoping in Javascript works.

You cannot access them outside of `B()` unless you pass references to them to other functions, return them from the function or you change the structure so they are declared or assigned to to a higher level scope rather than inside of `B()`.

---

For example, you can pass a reference to them to another function:

```
function B() {
    function C() { console.log('c'); }
    function D() { console.log('d'); }
    console.log('b');
    setTimeout(C, 1000);
}
```

Then, when you call `B()`, it will first output `b` and then 1 second later it will output `c`.

---

Or, you could change their structure by making those functions be properties of the `B` function object:

```
function B() {
    B.C = function() { console.log('c'); }
    B.D = function() { console.log('d'); }
    console.log('b');
}
```

Then, you can call `B()` or to get access to `C` or `D`, you call them like `B.C()`.

---

Or, you could return an object from `B()` that had both functions on it:

```
function B() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.C = function() { console.log('c'); }
    obj.D = function() { console.log('d'); }
    return obj;
}

var functions = B();
functions.C();
```

---

Or, you can make `B()` be a constructor function:

```
function B() {
    this.c = function() { console.log('c'); }
    this.d = function() { console.log('d'); }
    return obj;
}

var obj = new B();
obj.c();
```

FYI, a regular convention in Javascript is that constructor functions start with a capital letter and other functions/methods start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

As per javascript scope you cant access them from outside B().

You will have to modify B() in order to be able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

You have `B()` setup for use as a `constructor`.  If you want to access the inner functions of `B()`, you need to create a new instance of it with the `new` keyword.  However, `C()` and `D()` are private functions.  We can change them public functions like this:

```
function B() {
    console.log('b');
    this.C = function() { console.log('c'); } //public function
    function D() { console.log('d'); } //private function (no this keyword)
}
```

You then have to create an *instance* of `B()` to access its `public` values.

```
var b = new B(); //logs 'b'
b.C(); //logs 'c'
b.D(); //throws an error because D() is private
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to access C or D from outside B. Here's some alternative options:

```
function A() { console.log('a'); }
function B() {
    function C() { console.log('c'); }
    function D() { console.log('d'); }
    return {
       C: C,
       D: D
    };
}

B().C();
B().D();
```

or

```
var C, D;
function A() { console.log('a'); }
function B() {
    C = function() { console.log('c'); }
    D = function() { console.log('d'); }
}
B();
C();
D();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking for a way to pass argument to B without modifying it right ? ? so how about this ..

```
function ABC(arg){
 function B()
 {
  function C() { console.log('c'); }
  function D() { console.log('d'); }

  if (arg == 'C')
   C();
  if (arg == 'D')
   D();

  console.log('b');
 }

 B();
}
```

I am guessing that you are looking for a solution in this line.